# Drawing Graph Products

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I need to draw graphs that are Cartesian products of 2 graphs. I need them to look like this: [image].

So each copy of the factors can have `LinearEmbedding`, but the whole drawing should be based on grid-like skeleton. Clearly, vertices should be on nodes of the grid, and edges can be arbitrary. Are there any solutions?

In particular, for Grid Graphs the `SpringEmbedding` gives similar result, but even for Torus Graphs result is very different. I need to draw Cartesian products of complete graphs, cycles, paths, complete bipartite graphs, and add labels to edges of the products.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I do feel that the question could be a bit more clear.  When you write "each copy of the factors can have LinearEmbedding", do mean that each factor is, in fact, a path graph?  Assuming so, perhaps something like the following could work.  (Seems to complicated, I admit.)

```
m = 3;
n = 2;
g1 = Graph[
   Table[UndirectedEdge[Subscript[u, i], Subscript[u, i + 1]], {i, 1, m - 1}],
   VertexLabels -> "Name",
   VertexCoordinates -> Table[{0, i}, {i, 1, m}]
   ];
g2 = Graph[
   Table[UndirectedEdge[Subscript[u, i], Subscript[u, i + 1]], {i, 1, n - 1}],
   VertexLabels -> "Name",
   VertexCoordinates -> Table[{i, 0}, {i, 1, n}]
   ];
g1g2 = Graph[
   Flatten@Join[
     Table[
      UndirectedEdge[{Subscript[u, i], Subscript[u, j]}, 
        {Subscript[u, i], Subscript[u, j + 1]}], {i, 1, m}, {j, 1, n - 1}],
     Table[
      UndirectedEdge[{Subscript[u, i], Subscript[u, j]}, 
         {Subscript[u, i + 1], Subscript[u, j]}], {i, 1, m - 1}, {j, 1, n}]
     ],
   VertexLabels -> "Name",
   VertexCoordinates -> Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, m}, {j, 1, n}], 1]
   ];
size[1] = {100, 200};
size[2] = {200, 100};
size[3] = {300, 200};
Row[MapIndexed[Show[GraphComputation`GraphConvertToGraphics[#],
    ImageMargins -> 5, ImageSize -> size[#2[[1]]]] &, 
  {g1, g2, g1g2}],
 ImageSize -> 700, Alignment -> Center]
```

[image]

The bulk of this code involves the layout of the graph.  If you simply want a generalized Cartesian product of graphs without regard to the layout, then that's a bit easier.

```
SeedRandom[1];
g1 = RandomGraph[{5, 5},VertexLabels -> "Name"];
g2 = RandomGraph[{5, 8},VertexLabels -> "Name"];
makeCartesianProductEdge[u_, UndirectedEdge[u2_, v2_]] := UndirectedEdge[{u, u2}, {u, v2}];
makeCartesianProductEdge[UndirectedEdge[u1_, v1_], v_] := UndirectedEdge[{u1, v}, {v1, v}];
g1g2 = Graph[Flatten[{
     Table[makeCartesianProductEdge[u, e],{u, VertexList[g1]}, {e, EdgeList[g2]}],
     Table[makeCartesianProductEdge[e, u],{u, VertexList[g2]}, {e, EdgeList[g1]}]}], 
     VertexLabels -> "Name"];
graphToGraphics[g_Graph] := GraphComputation`GraphConvertToGraphics[g];
graphToGraphics[else_] := else;
GraphicsGrid[Partition[graphToGraphics /@ {g1, g2, g1g2, SpanFromLeft}, 2]]
```

[image]

If you want a linear embedding of non-path graphs, then you'll need to do something to keep the edges from lying on top of one another.

```
g1 = Graph[EdgeList[g1], VertexCoordinates -> Table[{i, 0}, {i, 1, Length[VertexList[g1]]}]];
g2 = Graph[EdgeList[g2], VertexCoordinates -> Table[{i, 0}, {i, 1, Length[VertexList[g2]]}]];
g1g2 = Graph[EdgeList[g1g2], VertexCoordinates -> VertexList[g1g2]]
```

[image]

Perhaps the following `EdgeShapeFunction` will help, but I doubt it.

```
esf[{u_, v_}, ___] := {Opacity[0.3], Arrow[BSplineCurve[Table[
  (u + v)/2 + Norm[v - u] {Cos[t], Sin[t]}/2,
  {t, ArcTan @@ (v - u), ArcTan @@ (v - u) + Pi, Pi/5}]]]};
GraphicsRow[SetProperty[#, EdgeShapeFunction -> esf] & /@ {g1, g2, g1g2}]
```

[image]

Comment: @R.M I got the impression he was looking for the Cartesian product of arbitrary path graphs (note the parameters m and n). Hence, my question about linear embeddings.

Comment: I stand corrected. While my interpretation was the same as yours, I didn't pay closer attention to your code. Very nice! :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I've noted that I need to draw Cartesian products of complete graphs, paths, cycles etc. If each factor is a path graph, then the product is `GridGraph` for which `SpringEmbedding` is nice. 
I wrote I needed `LinearEmbedding` because for `GraphPlot` that option produced a drawing with curved, non-overlapping edges, same result that you got using `EdgeShapeFunction`

Comment: So the last part of the answer is what I needed :) Two important things I learned: 1. how to effectively construct Cartesian product for `Graph` objects; 2. how to use `EdgeShapeFunction`. Hope this will be enough to achieve all my goals. Thanks again.

Comment: hmm.. I couldn't recreate the last drawings you've attached. Output for your code  is `SetProperty[ (* image here *), EdgeShapeFunction->esf]`, so it doesn't work. I tried to use your `EdgeShapeFunction` for `g1` only: `Graph[EdgeList[g1], EdgeShapeFunction -> esf, VertexCoordinates -> Table[{i, 0}, {i, 1, Length[VertexList[g1]]}]]` and I get `ArcTan::indet: "Indeterminate expression ArcTan[0.,0.] encountered."`.

Comment: it seems something like this `BSplineCurve[{u, u + (Norm[v - u] - 1)/3, v}]` is OK (near vertices are joined with a straight line)

Comment: @HrantKhachatrian Hmm... I just copied and pasted the code from the page into a fresh session of Mathematica and it worked fine.  I'm using V8.0.4 on Mac OSX

Comment: My version is 8.0.0. Maybe that's the issue. Anyway, I use simpler curves [with just 3 points] and have easier control over them [to make edges from one "level" not to reach other "levels"]. Here is a result: http://imgur.com/qdjm0